# ExpireAfterRead/Write/Update support in redis clients

Tags: redis, redisson, caffeine-cache

Does any of the java redis clients support the above primitives in their api for TTL? I am using redisson currently. This is supported by the in-memory cache lib like caffeine.

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the expire after each of these commands?

Comment: basically ability to set TTL based on more than one of these. e.g. ExpireAfterRead and ExpireAfterWrite whichever expires will hit TTL for the entry

Comment: you can register for keyspace notifications see: https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ttl` parameter with RMapCache object duing `put` method invocation which will be analog of `expireAfterWrite` method and definition of `idleTimeout` parameter will be analog of `expireAfterAccess` method.